# Android MVP: login credential validation

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp, android-mvp

I started learning MVP in the last couple of days and I found this interesting [tutorial](https://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/). I followed the code step by step to implement login functionality in my app. However, I still have difficulties understanding where the input validation should be! In the tutorial inside the `LoginInteractorImpl` class inside the login method (2 functionalities in one method!). My questions is, why would I have to reach the Interactor class to validate the credentials? Why not validating the input in the `Presenter` class and if the input is correct I pass it to the Interactor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `presenter` is the glue between your `views` and your `models` all it does is exchange the information between the two. It shouldn't be doing any kind of logic, only it's designated task. Read about [Seperation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

What would happen if you need to implement another login screen and you want to use the same logic from your `LoginInteractor`? You'd have to add validation logic to your new presenter. Or what if you change your validation technique?

Changing the logic should not have an effect on the presenter, and vice-versa. The presenter is only concerned with passing information.

Comment: Thank you! It is all about reusability.

Answer (score 1):

The input validation could be inside the view or the presenter, but is not the idea. The idea is to have all the "business logic" inside the interactor, while the activity is "dumber" as possible, and the presenter is the link between those two.